# No main breaker?

Tags: electrical-panel

Why don't I have a main breaker? At least I don't see one. Our home was built in 2019. I'm wanting to swap the bottom breaker for a 60A and use 6 gauge wire. [image: breaker box]

Comment: Note that 6 gauge wire is only legal to 55A.  If the load provisions to 51-55A, then you can use a 60A breaker with it, otherwise should be 50A breaker.  If this is electric vehicle charging, first [watch this, *please*](https://youtu.be/Iyp_X3mwE1w?t=1693) before you spend a lot of money, and second note that "60A breaker"/48A actual won't work with #6 NM or UF.   Needs #4 for that. However you can commission the charger at 50A (40A) instead and that'll work.  (or 55A if offered, but no one offers that :( ) There is no such thing as 60A wire.  #4Al is good to 65A and #4Cu is good for 70A.

Answer (score 25):

If a newer house check at the meter.

There has to be a main breaker somewhere.

Most main breakers are now on the outside so fire department can turn off the power without going though fire/smoke or climbing a pole.

Answer (score 12):

Look around where your meter is installed. There will usually be a panel where you'll find your disconnect. You should be able to access it since it's not supposed to be sealed or locks. If you live in a condo or apartment, the disconnect will be in the meter room.

Comment: External meter/main combos _should_ be padlocked to keep the meddling kids from messing with it. As the owner, the OP should have the key/combination to the lock. As Harper always notes, the fire department has a [master key](https://mobileimages.lowes.com/productimages/b94db301-e567-4a09-98d2-b3a7f3d601f1/03235066.jpg?size=md)

Comment: @freeman: some jurisdictions are more organized/rigorous than others. Some don't feel the need to protect the box from tampering at all, and others use frangible padlocks that can be shattered open with a hammer rather than master-keyed. Tradeoffs. Check with the Local Authority Having Jurisdiction (typically town inspector's office here) for local rules on what is and isn't permissable.

Comment: As the homeowner, @keshlam, **I** want the box to be locked to keep them meddlin' kids out of it! The municipality doesn't care, and the power company has their tamper evident "lock shaped device of thin wire and plastic" protecting their side of the equation.

Comment: As I said: different areas, different concerns and codes.if your municipality doesn't care, that's your answer. Elsewhere, different. (I have trouble imagining local kids stupid enough to think this was a good idea, but then I have trouble imagining  a lot of stupidities, and again regional issues differ.)

Comment: @keshlam They think turning off the power is a fun prank.  Or a way to get back at the people living there if they did something the kids didn't like.  (Grew up next to some kids where the parents would only punish wrongdoing they saw, otherwise they would absolutely believe their kids did no wrong even when it was obvious they did.  Last I knew those kids had spent the majority of their adult life in jail.)

Comment: Your mileage will vary. Void where prohibited by law. ASK THE LOCAL AUTHORITY HAVING JURISDICTION.

Comment: @keshlam I'm not sure if you looked at that image of a padlock "master key"; it's a pair of bolt cutters.

Comment: @cjs: Yep, missed that.  Tnx.

Comment: @FreeMan   like the "master key"

Comment: Borrowed the "master key" concept & image link from Harper. Cannot claim credit for that one at all! (This time. Next time, I'll say "this guy I know says...". After that, it's "As I've always said..." :D )